# Вывод ASCII символов при помощи bat файла

Tags: cmd, bat, ascii

Мне нужно вывести символы ASCII в cmd через bat файлы. После 126-го символа ничего не выводится. Мне нужны символы включительно. Хелп плиз ^_^

```
@echo off
chcp 1251
for /l %%i in (33,1,255) do (   
    call :_tochar %%i
    cmd /c exit %%i
)
exit /b

:_tochar
setlocal
cmd /c exit %1
echo %1 "%=exitcodeAscii%"
exit /b
```

[image: Воть]

Comment: Я предлагаю воспользоваться внешними (по отношению к интерпретатору Windows CMD) средствами: Powershell (`powershell.exe`),Windows Script Host (`cscript.exe`, `mshta.exe`). Пример VBscript-команды: `WScript.StdOut.WriteLine chr (127)`

Comment: И самый главный момент. Символы ASCII с номером более 126 относятся к символам расширенной таблицы ASCII Codes. Поэтому их графическая интерпретация может ... внезапно... оказаться зависимой от кодовой страницы экрана! Поэтому нужно определиться: что Вы хотите получить, в какой интерпретации?

Comment: Попробовал powershell, результат тот же. Вообще говоря, я пытался использовать разные кодировки, например 65001 но не выходило. Также менял шрифт cmd, вдруг не поддерживает какие-то символы, также безуспешно

Comment: Так если пробовали и не вышло, приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода.